# Unable to validate/publish customization project in Acumatica 2019R2

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am attempting to validate my customization project before upgrading from 2019R1 to 2019R2.  The error messages are not specific enough to be much use in diagnosing the problems, and seem to be referring to objects in the Acumatica code base.

```
Validating Binary Files
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PrimaryKeyOf`1/By`1/ForeignKeyOf`1 declared in PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PrimaryKeyOf`1/By`1/ForeignKeyOf`1/By`1 declared in PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.Objects.PO.POLineType/Goods/Provider declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Fixed binding: splits from PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptEntry
Fixed binding: Item from PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemMaintBase
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PrimaryKeyOf`1/By`1/ForeignKeyOf`1/By`1::.ctor() declared in PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PrimaryKeyOf`1/By`1/ForeignKeyOf`1/By`1::.ctor() declared in PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PrimaryKeyOf`1/By`1/ForeignKeyOf`1/By`1::.ctor() declared in PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
MyProject.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PrimaryKeyOf`1/By`1/ForeignKeyOf`1/By`1::.ctor() declared in PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
```

I attempted to unpublish all customization, upgrade, and open my project in visual studio to find the specific errors, but there were none.  The customization project subsequently published successfully, but I was missing data from custom objects.

Any suggestions for determining what I need to change in my customization project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been building the Acumatica website within the project, without success. I eventually was able to publish with no apparent weirdnesses after I changed the .NET version of the website project to 4.8 and was able to publish, although I'm not certain if that's what made the difference or just hitting it repeatedly with a hammer did the trick.

Comment: if the site was upgraded from 19R1 to 19R2 - try to first unpublished all customizations. It could be that some customizations while already published in the site will have problems after Acumatica is upgraded? For example the code that might live in the App_RuntimeCode folder of the site

Answer (score 1):

I would check if during build you used dll of proper Acumatica version.